# Touchpad not detected in Aspire VN7-591G

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, touchpad, acer-aspire

I have Acer Aspire VN7-591G and my touchpad is not working.
I installed Windows 8.1 Professional N. I installed all updates. Then I install drivers from Acer site and nothing happened. Next, I use live CD linux and tried with that but it does not detect touchpad neither. What can I do more to solve this issue?

My device manager screen:
[DEVICE MANAGER SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCEln.jpg)

My BIOS screens:
[BIOS SCREENS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAhjG.jpg)

Comment: Does the Acer site have Windows 8 drivers for the touchpad? Do you know the OEM of the touchpad?  Possibly they have drivers.  Your device manager clearly shows an issue.  "Unknown Device Identifier" may help you solve this.  Says it supports Windows 8

Comment: Yes there is a driver on Acer website and I installed it. I do not know the OEM of touchpad, how can I access this information? Unfortunately "Unknown Device Identifer" crashes when I try to run it. I ran device manager and the id of unknown device is **USB\VID04B4&PID00FA&REV_0000**. Using google does not help

Comment: Is this an Intel chipset mainboard?  If so, did you run the Intel chipset update/driver install? If you identify an Intel chipset, the package can be found at the Intel site if not offered by Acer.  Sometimes a key board component is missing a driver and then the attached device fails. Sorry I cannot read the screen shot for device manager to guide you further

Comment: Yes it is intel chipset mainboard. Yes I ran the Intel chipset driver install that I found on Acer website. I am attaching the screenshot of device manager in English, hope you can help me. [LINK](http://imgur.com/a/kzRaY)

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. My touchpad is working, but only in a limited fashion. I assume you already tried fn+F7 (to enable the touchpad)?
Manually installing the touchpad drivers from the Acer website gives an error that there are no 64bit drivers included, which might be the issue...And the generic Synaptic drivers don't work either.

Comment: @Nathan I tried everything. I did not solve this issue. I simply returned the notebook, bought one with OS installed (I found one with the same price) and everything is working perfectly  :)